# Error in installing JomSocial in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, xampp, joomla-extensions

I got an error when I installing `JomSocial` in my `Joomla` Project in my `Extension Manager`.

it says that the `Installing component was successful.` but i got this error

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\administrator\components\com_community\install.community.php on line 39
```

actually I am new with Joomla things and i don't have any idea about this error. can anyone can help me about my case?

thanks in advance ...

Comment: what version of php does your host use? If your other computer installed it without an error but this one did, then it isn't anything to do with the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the joomla version and Joomsocial version are compatible to each other....

Comment: i have a `joomla 2.5.4`. my other computer did install it without the error, but this computer got this error.

Comment: @gadss hmmm sometime these kind of problem can be headache for us...:)